# Can't display OpenCV VideoCapture in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, video-capture

I want to display the content of my VideoCapture in a QGraphicsView, however if I run the Program my WebCam activates, but nothing is displayed onto my GraphicsView. This is what happen if I run this on my laptop, however if I run this on my PC, it works fine.

Do you know what's the issue here?

Codes:

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTimer>

#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    void Update();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    cv::VideoCapture videoCap;
    cv::Mat liveImage;
    QImage image;
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    videoCap.open(0);

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Update()));
    timer->start(20);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::Update()
{
    videoCap.read(liveImage);

    image = QImage(liveImage.data, liveImage.cols, liveImage.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
    scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    ui->graphicsView->show();
}
```

Comment: can you share the screen, is it a blank black screen ? Your camera is working with any camera app in that platform ?

Comment: plz, specify OS

Comment: just found the issue here, I forgot to add the `Update()` method under "public slots:" instead of "public:" in the mainwindow.h file.